# Working remotely for an offshore company while on a working holiday visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, ireland, working-holiday-visas

I am an Australian, looking to move to Ireland on a Working Holiday Authorization. My question is not taxation related.

Can I possibly work for my company in Australia remotely (over the internet) while living in Ireland on a WHA, or is it a visa requirement to work for a company in Ireland?

I presumed WHA gives one the right to work, but one could technically live there without work too as long as one can prove that they have sufficient funds? But, I read some conflicting information over the internet.

Cheers

---

### Reply from Embassy of Ireland in Australia

There is no legal requirement for  you to work for an Irish based company.  You may need to talk to an accountant about where you will be tax-resident if working for an Australian company remotely in Ireland.

This should still not preclude you from travelling to Ireland on a WHA, the primary purpose of which is for an extended holiday allowing for casual work to support oneself.

Comment: Post the reply you got as an answer to the question. You can answer your own questions on se sites. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only information I found from any source including [DFA](https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/working-holiday-visas/) is:

> Applicants must have sufficient funds to support themselves for at least the initial part of the holiday or in the event of failing to secure employment.

There doesn't seem to be a requirement that you must secure employment in order continue remaining in the country under the Working Holiday Authorization scheme.

There may be court decisions that have been made w.r.t. the WHA but if that is the case they are not public domain even though they are probably a public record.

Comment: Thanks, Karlson, you are right. I will post the reply I got from the embassy of Ireland in Australia.